# xev does not show names for function keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, laptop, openbox

I have function keys on my laptop, for instance `XF86AudioLowerVolume`. I can associate this key with some command in my openbox configuration file, and use it to lower/increase audio volume.

I found the name of this function key with `xev` command:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x196, subw 0x0, time 85289390, (524,165), root:(525,203),
    state 0x10, keycode 174 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

However, for my other function keys, `xev` does not show proper key names. For instance, the key which is supposed to be used to "**decrease screen brightness**". When pressed, `xev` shows `NoSymbol`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 43, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x196, subw 0x0, time 2651872, (850,161), root:(851,199),
    state 0x10, keycode 101 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 43, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x196, subw 0x0, time 2651872, (850,161), root:(851,199),
    state 0x10, keycode 101 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The other, paired key "**increase screen brightness**" also shows `NoSymbol`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 43, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x196, subw 0x0, time 2653165, (850,161), root:(851,199),
    state 0x10, keycode 212 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 43, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x196, subw 0x0, time 2653165, (850,161), root:(851,199),
    state 0x10, keycode 212 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Only the `keycode` is different for these two keys.

Does it mean I cannot use these keys to associate these with some command?
They clearly work as keyboard keys, why does `xev` show `NoSymbol` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NoSymbol` simply means that there is no predefined name for that key.  Those are listed in the file [`keysymdefs.h`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/keysymdef.h), which hasn't changed appreciably in the past twenty-odd years (see [this](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/keysymdef.h) for example, or [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xlib-reference-manual/9780937175262/16_appendix-h.html)).

That file is used to generate a list of names which `xev` and related programs consult.  For `xev`, that's done using either

- `XLookupString`, or
- `XmbLookupString`.

Either way, it relies upon a table generated from `keysymdef.h`, as noted in the source code:

- [`makekeys.c`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/src/util/makekeys.c#n29)

```
    /* Constructs hash tables for XStringToKeysym and XKeysymToString. */
```

- [`Makefile.am`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/src/Makefile.am#n411)

```
    # Building ks_tables.h requires the makekeys utility
```

No one really wants to add to that file, because it  is a mixture of codes corresponding to (but not matching) Unicode and special function keys such as the one you asked about.  Most of the special keys were defined before the X keyboard extension was introduced in the early 1990s, and that (Xkb) essentially settles for just identifying keys according to the row and column where they are found on a keyboard, rather than trying to name everything.

[This page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys.html) has links to tables illustrating how xterm uses key-modifiers.  The **`Name`** column of [Keymap tables](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys-us-pc105.html#key_map) is the name used by Xkb, which you can see is usually just row/column, except for ***very*** common keys such as `ESC` (for <kbd>*Escape*</kbd>).

Comment: so how can I reference the key in my openbox config file?

Comment: According to [this](https://techpiezo.com/linux/key-bindings-in-openbox/), you can use the keycode.  Alternatively, you can always use xmodmap to assign a keysym (e.g., a name) to a keycode.